# how to use lookup with a condition using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions, aggregation

have two collections with values

how to use lookup with a condition using MongoDB aggregation

first collection: basic_info

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas",
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

second collection : test_results

```
[
 {
    basic_id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    test_results:"PASS",

  },
  {
    basic_id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    test_results:"PASS",
  },
  {
    basic_id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    test_results:"FAIL",
  }
]
```

Lookup with condition where `test_results: PASS` and `test_results: FAIL,` should be excluded

expected_output after aggregation using lookup:

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",
    test_results:"PASS"

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas",
    test_results:"PASS"
  }
]
```

MongoDB version: 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MongoDB v3.6, we can perform [uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) with `$lookup`.

It returns list of matched results from `test_results` collection `0 ... N` (in your case, it would be `0 ... 1`). The next step, we filter empty `test_results` fields (non-matched documents).

In the last stage, we transform document into desired output result. `$replaceRoot` operator allows transform:

```
{                                      {
  ... other fields                       ... other fields
  test_results : [           ---->
    {test_results:"PASS"}    ---->       test_results:"PASS"
  ]
}                                      }
```

---

Try the query below:

```
db.basic_info.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "test_results",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            test_results: "PASS",
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$basic_id",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            test_results: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "test_results"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "test_results.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$test_results",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sQhbnBfgW2m)

**Trick:** Since you need only `test_results:"PASS"` from `test_results` collection, we can change `$replaceRoot` to `$addFields`:

```
{
  $addFields: {
    test_results: "PASS"
  }
}
```